# How do you embed a JsFiddle as an iFrame in HTML only?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, jsfiddle

This is what happens when I embed the JsFiddle into my website as a result:

[http://i.imgur.com/JkDefod.png](https://i.imgur.com/JkDefod.png)

What can I do so that my embedded JsFiddle only shows the running program and not the extra text above?

Here is my JsFiddle code:

```js
var handler = function() {
  if (--sec < 0) {
    sec = 59;
    if (--min < 0) {
      min = 0;
      sec = 0;
    }
  }
  var min1 = "0" + min + "m";
  var min2 = min + "m";
  var sec1 = "0" + sec + "s";
  var sec2 = sec + "s";
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (min < 10 ? min1.fontcolor("red") : min2.fontcolor("red")) + ":".fontcolor("red") + (sec < 10 ? sec1.fontcolor("red") : sec2.fontcolor("red"));
};
var sec = 0;
var min = 15;
handler();
setInterval(handler, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="worked"></div>
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Offer Ends In:</strong></span></h1>
<h1 id="time" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</h1>
```

Comment: Why don't you just add code straight to your page?

Answer (score 3):

You can directly add this code in your page, or using the JsFiddle embeded, do like this:

```
<div class="someClass">
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/DiogoBernardelli/vuc85mok/embed/result/"></script>
</div>
```

And add this in your Stylesheet (.css) file:

```
.someClass iframe {
height: 200px //you can manually change this height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add only this countdown timer on your web-page, why don't you add your JS code in the  tags after your divs?

Something like this:

```
<body>

<div id="worked"></div>
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Offer Ends In:</strong></span></h1>
<h1 id="time" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</h1>

</body>

<script>
var handler = function() {
  if (--sec < 0) {
    sec = 59;
    if (--min < 0) {
      min = 0;
      sec = 0;
    }
  }
  var min1 = "0" + min + "m";
  var min2 = min + "m";
  var sec1 = "0" + sec + "s";
  var sec2 = sec + "s";
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (min < 10 ? min1.fontcolor("red") : min2.fontcolor("red")) + ":".fontcolor("red") + (sec < 10 ? sec1.fontcolor("red") : sec2.fontcolor("red"));
};
var sec = 0;
var min = 15;
handler();
setInterval(handler, 1000);
</script>
```